# Open a modal using a link

Tags: html, bootstrap-modal

I want to open a picture in a modal using a link in the text(verslag.txt). I want to use one modal, the link should tell the modal which picture to load in the modal.

The text(verslag.txt) is loaded into a div by a load command and I'm not sure where to put the modal code. In the txt file that I load or in the html file where the load command and the div are in.

The code below is when I put the in the verslag.txt file.

The code to load my verslag.txt file info the div

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#middiv").load("verslag2.txt");
});
</script>
```

The total div structure in my html file;

```
<div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
  <!--Ik gebruik hieronder alleen het middiv omdat dat de enige info is die ik wil vervangen-->
    <div class="col-md-12 scrollbarclass" id="middiv" syle="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The link I use in the verslag.txt

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">laatste2</a>
```

The modal code currently also in verslag.txt

```
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> 
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4> 
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> </button>
      </div> 
      <div class="modal-body">
      <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer"> 
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Links
The html file 
    https://lodysreizen.nl/toonverslag2.html
The txt file 
    https://lodysreizen.nl/verslag2.txt

Answer (score 0):

You should try to resolve these errors. Check your dev console.

[image: js errors]

Comment: Ok, I think the error is gone. Is the code correct?